# Is it possible to "mute" cells in ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

Image you have to run an ipython notebook over and over again but you want to exclude specific cells every now and then. At the moment I'm handling this by commenting out the cells I want to exclude. It works but it is quite tedious.

Is there an easier way to mute cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of cell to `Raw NBConvert`.

The code won't run, nor will it cause any output for that cell.